# convert Curl request address To httpUrlConnection request and get response

Tags: android, api, curl, httpurlconnection, lyft-api

How can I put client id and client secret into httprequest?

```
           /*
            curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           --user "<client_id>:<client_secret>" \
        -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "public"}' \
        'https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token'
      */

  URL url = new URL("https://api.lyft.com/oauth/token");
           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
           conn.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "client_credentials");
           conn.setRequestProperty("scope", "public");
           //conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token token=" + accessToken);
           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

***Getting httpStatus : 400***

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See [4.4.2. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2) of [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework) for details.